# Creating a singly linked list of BlockType structures

Tags: c, linked-list, typedef

I'm trying to create a singly linked list with these 3 `typedef struct` (person, Stats, and vehicle).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct{
  char name[22];
  char city[10];
  int yearBorn;
}  person;


typedef struct{
  int height[8];
  double weight[18];
  }  Stats;

typedef struct{
 char car[16];
 int horsepower[20];
}  vehicle;


typedef struct node {
   person   *p; 
   Stats *stat;
   vehicle *hp;
   struct node *next;
}NODE;

typedef struct {
   NODE *head, *tail;
}SLL;


int main(){
void insert(SLL *list, person p, vehicle hp,  Stats stat){


a = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(p));
b = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(hp));
c = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(stat));

if(list->head == NULL){
 return NULL;
}
list -> head -> next = a;
list -> head -> next-> next  = b;
list -> head -> next-> next -> next = c;
list -> tail = c;


}




return 0;
}
```

I Keep on getting errors for a, b, & c saying **error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)**.
I'm just wondering if I am doing doing this properly, and what this error means.
I truly appreciate any insight about my code. Thank you.

Comment: U need to declare variable before using it . Here a,b,c is not declared and you are using it  directly .

Comment: what do I declare it as? an unsigned char?

Comment: No you are not doing this properly. If you were you would not get error messages from the compiler. The error message means exactly what it says. The problem with your code is that there is not a single correct or meaningful line after `int main()`. Before attempting to rewrite it you need to spend a couple of hours refreshing basic notions of function, variable and type.

Comment: It must be of type what you have used for type casting before malloc call. So must know for what type (ie structure) you creating  memory on heap using malloc . Also put that function out of main

Comment: Did you come from a Python background?  In C, you must declare variables before using them.  Also you can't define functions inside functions.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is here

```
int main(){
    void insert(SLL *list, person p, vehicle hp,  Stats stat){


    a = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(p));
    b = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(hp));
    c = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(stat));

      if(list->head == NULL){
         return NULL;
      }
    list -> head -> next = a;
    list -> head -> next-> next  = b;
    list -> head -> next-> next -> next = c;
    list -> tail = c;
    }

return 0;
}
```

How can you define a function inside other function?!!